# How to create a buffer solution from NaOH and CH₃COOH?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

In my chemistry book, they say that an approach to making a buffer solution of $\mathrm{pH}=5.09$ is by adding an appropriate amount of strong base $(0.052\ \mathrm{mol}\ \ce{NaOH})$ to $0.300\ \mathrm{l}$ of $0.025\ \mathrm{mol/l}\ \ce{CH3COOH}$. But, I haven’t been able to figure out how they got those numbers. If I am not mistaken the relevant equation is,

$$\ce{CH3COOH +OH- <=>CH3COO^- + H_2O}$$

where the weak acid and conjugate base are respectively $\ce{CH3COOH}$ and $\ce{CH3COO^-}$. My concern is that this equation above goes nearly to completion $(K=1.8\times10^9)$ so I don’t see how this can even be a buffer solution. If not, how do they get the values? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try considering reaction stoichiometry. You know the extent of the reaction. Now consider stoichiometry.

EDIT: If these are really the numbers your textbook gave you, then the textbook is wrong; you cannot create a buffer system with these numbers specifically. I suspect that you didn't transcribe the numbers from your textbook correctly. In any case the general idea, however, is correct - you can indeed form a buffer solution using sodium hydroxide and a solution of acetic acid.

All you have to do to realize this is to know what a buffer is - a buffer has significant concentrations of both an acid and its conjugate base (or base and its conjugate acid) - and consider reaction stoichiometry.

Comment: If the reaction goes to completion then what would happen to the buffer when you add a base, since there is no weak acid left. Can you please be more concise? I copied the answers verbatim, if they are wrong can you suggest correct answers.

Comment: "what would happen to the buffer when you add a base, since there is no weak acid left."

Do you always run out of acid when you add base? What if you add _less_ strong base than you have _acid_? That was my point. _Consider reaction stoichiometry_.

Comment: So, the amount of OH-(~NaOH) should be half that of the weak acid?

Comment: If you want a one to one acid to conjugate base concentration buffer, yes. Not all buffers must have such a ratio.

Comment: So, I am missing one more equation $\ce{CH3COOH +H2O <=> H3O+ +CH3COO-}$, where the concentration of $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is defined by the excess. After this its like any other buffer, we use the $K_a$ of the equation above and $[\ce{H3O+}]=K_a \frac{[\ce{CH3OOH}]_{\text{excess}}}{[\ce{CH3COO-}]}$

Comment: I believe they had done a typo error it should be 0.25 M CH3COOH.

Comment: I think that would be a more reasonable molarity for acetic acid in this case.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted then, so this question can be closed.